# How to create custom wildcard domain with Microsoft's domain (azurewebsites.net)

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, azure-web-app-service, wildcard-subdomain

I refer follwing link :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-custom-domain-name#a

but When I am going to create custom domain it show following error.

No CNAME were found. Please add a CNAME record pointing to dev-demo.azurewebsites.net.

Please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, what you need to do is set up a CNAME record to pointing to your Azure app's default domain for your domain registered at your domain registrar's own management tool (e.g. Azure DNS, GoDaddy, etc.).

If you registered your domain name with GoDaddy, please follow the steps blow.

1. Log in to your [GoDaddy](http://godaddy.com) account.
2. Click on your account icon, then navigate to **Manage My Domains**.

[image]

3. Select the domain you want to manage, under the Action section, click on the **Manage DNS** button:

[image]

4. At the **Records** section, click **Add** and select **CNAME** from the drop-down list.
5. Complete the fields, then click **Save** button.

[image]

6. Now, go back to the [Azure portal](http://portal.azure.com), and validate your hostname again.
   [image]